# Deallocating a pointer inside a structure within another structure

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I was given the following paraphrased question:
"Using only the variable q, dynamically allocate memory for the integer pointers inside the struct point". I wrote the following code, however, I am unable to delete the dynamically allocated integer, as it gives me a run-time error saying I am deleting something that does not exist. I checked the memory address of 
((*q) -> x -> x) and srcX after assignment, and they have the same address. How can I free this dynamically allocated integer?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point {
    int *x;
    int *y;
};

struct line {
    struct point *x;
    struct point *y;
};

void create_line (int srcX, int srcY, int dstX, int dstY) {
    struct line *p;
    struct line **q = &p;
    (*q) = new line;
    (*q) -> x = new point;
    (*q) -> x -> x = new int;
    (*q) -> x -> x = &srcX;
    cout << *((*q)->x->x) << endl;
    delete (*q)->x->x; // Causing run-time error
    delete (*q)->x;
    delete (*q);
}

int main(){
    create_line(2,3,7,8);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion here

```
(*q) -> x -> x = new int;
(*q) -> x -> x = &srcX;
```

The first line points `x` to a new integer but the next line overwrites it to point to `srcX`, losing the previously allocated memory. Since what `x` points to was not created with `new`, it should not be `delete`d, hence the error.

You do not need to allocate with `new` if you already have what you're pointing to (unless you intend to copy the value into the newly created memory).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in the second assignment to x in point structure.

```
(*q) -> x -> x = new int; // here you are allocating new memory for x
(*q) -> x -> x = &srcX;   // here you override the address you got from prev allocation
```

So what actually happens is that `(*q) -> x -> x` will hold the address to the newly allocated memory from `new int` let's say address 0x1000. In the next line `(*q) -> x -> x` will hold the address to the passed argument `srcX` lets sat 0x2000.
So what you are getting is that the address to the memory that you allocated using `new` is now gone and this memory is now gone, and when you will reach `delete (*q)->x->x` you will get an error because what happens is that you are trying to release memory that you haven't allocated using `new`.

I think you should change the function to look like this:

```
void create_line (int srcX, int srcY, int dstX, int dstY) {
    struct line *p;
    struct line **q = &p;
    (*q) = new line;
    (*q) -> x = new point;
    // (*q) -> x -> x = new int; -> no need to allocate memory
    (*q) -> x -> x = &srcX;
    cout << *((*q)->x->x) << endl;
    // delete (*q)->x->x;        -> no need to free it
    delete (*q)->x;
    delete (*q);
}
```